# centos 7 install java version 1.6.0_45 and PostgreSQL 9.3.16

Tags: java, linux, postgresql

I used centos 7 
And I have already java and PostgreSQL which are installed to my system

this is the java version and PostgreSQL version :

```
java -version
```

**java version "1.6.0_45"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment ( build 1.6.0_45-b06)**

```
SELECT version();
```

**"PostgreSQL 9.3.16 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit"**

I want to install the same java version and PostgreSQL version in another centos system (PostgreSQL **9.3.16** and java **1.6.0_45**)

I didn't find the correct command .

I try using this command to install java

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 -y
```

but I find another java version :

```
java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_102"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You probably have both Java 8 and Java 6 installed. Have you tried configuring using `alternatives --config java`?  Read "man alternatives".